# How to leave only specific columns?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider the following table:

```
tabtest = 
 Join[{{"a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e"}}, 
  RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 8}]]
```

Could you please tell me how to leave extract only the columns starting with, say, `"a"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you transpose your data you can use "Cases" like:

```
Cases[Transpose[tabtest], {"a", __}] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps this:

```
SeedRandom[0];
tabtest = 
  Join[{{"a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e"}}, 
   RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 8}]];

tabtest[[All, Flatten@Position[First@tabtest, "a", 1]]]
(*
{{"a", "a"}, {1.65247, 1.63307}, {1.1011, 1.64552}, {1.87669, 
  1.01913}, {1.28242, 1.29648}, {1.43271, 1.12359}, {1.95713, 
  1.63538}, {1.02266, 1.16359}, {1.09437, 1.79686}, {1.746, 
  1.49077}, {1.44829, 1.44897}}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
tabtest[[All,PositionIndex[First@tabtest]["a"]]]

(* {
    {a,a},
    {1.1943,1.28724},
    {1.78077,1.23776},
    {1.86472,1.81003},
    {1.41396,1.81898},
    {1.32723,1.97021},
    {1.66714,1.79951},
    {1.15126,1.05214},
    {1.95384,1.30154},
    {1.61523,1.98808},
    {1.65683,1.50416}
   } *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Extract[Position[tabtest[[1]], "a"]] /@ tabtest
```

or

```
Select[Transpose[tabtest], First/*EqualTo["a"]] // Transpose
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dt = MapApply[#1 -> {##2} &] @ Transpose[tabtest];

Lookup[#, "a", Nothing] & /@ dt // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another method using `Tally`:

```
f[tab_, lab_] := 
If[MemberQ[Last /@ Position[tab, lab], 1] === False, 
Transpose@(Rest @@ (Most@*Transpose@Tally[Transpose@tab, FreeQ[{#1, #2}, lab] &])), 
Transpose@(Most @@ (Most@*Transpose@Tally[Transpose@tab, FreeQ[{#1, #2}, lab] &]))]
```

Example:

```
f[tabtest, "a"] // MatrixForm
```

[image]